# How to detect an environment variable in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 3 environments. 1 Dev, 1 Staging and 1 PROD

I want to create an env variable so that when the application runs, it knows if its in Dev or Staging or PROD.

I'm guessing that I can add this to the Web.config file. If this is true, how can I do it? And how can i use it in my View?